# Powershell to download ARM template for Azure data factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

i have a requirement to create an ADF pipeline using ARM template in powershell and it has to take inputs/validate few things from existing ADF piepline, for that reason i have to download the ARM tempalte for existing ADF pipeline through powershell. Can we do that for single ADF pipeline or multiple ones?
Note: existing pipeline is not created through ARM deployment, so i cant use "Save-AzureRmDeploymentTemplate" as i dont have deployment name created when pipeline is created through portal..

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look at [Export-AzureRmResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/export-azurermresourcegroup?view=azurermps-6.12.0). 
But I guess you can only export the entire resource group which may contain other things. You need put your data factory in a special resource group if you only want to export ADF.

Another way is to export arm template in ADF UI.

Comment: Thanku, but "Export-AzureRmResourceGroup" throws me an warning as below and none of ADF related schema is downloaded..
    WARNING: ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound : The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template.