# Is there a way to export ADF content via command line?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF and I see there's a button to export the files. Is there a way to export them via command line? From any branch, similar to the UI feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
From the adf_publish branch, we can view the published ARM template in Github.

---

1. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-cli#export-resource-groups-to-templates), the export template feature doesn't support exporting Azure Data Factory resources.
2. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-clone-data-factory#how-to-clone-a-data-factory). We can configure Github repo in ADF and the repo will store all the resources of the ADF.
3. After we published the ADF, we can see all the resources are synchronized to  Github, then we can use git command `git clone` to download the resource of the ADF.

[image]

Comment: no, I meant the export button in the ARM template dropdown

Comment: Powershell is not support to download the ARM template due to security issue, I've tried but got same error as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339725/powershell-to-download-arm-template-for-azure-data-factory-pipeline).

Comment: From the adf_publish branch, we can view the published ARM template in Github.

Comment: yes, Joseph, but just from the master branch. The export branch works for any branch.

Comment: So we can  export the ARM template via git bash command line?

Comment: that's what I want to know. from the button I can export from any branch, but is there a cmd that I can use? so I dont need to actually click the button?

Comment: I've checked a lot of information, but there is no information that supports command line export of ADF ARM templates. I guess it may be due to security reasons. What we can do is export from the UI or switch branches and then export using Git clone.

Comment: yeah, I am considering writting a selenium script to programatically click the button. Juts have to figure out authentication though